# How to Hide and show element between 2 UL elements

Tags: jquery, html

i have 2 Ul elements with LI

```
<ul>
   <li id="rightli1">item1</li>
   <li id="rightli2">item2</li>
   <li id="rightli3">item3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li id="leftli1">item1</li>
   <li id="leftli2">item2</li>
   <li id="leftli3">item3</li>
</ul>
```

here, if i click on `id = rightli1` , it should hide and other `leftli1` should be visible, same like vice versa, how could i do that? it's something like drag and drop functionality

Comment: Do you have any JS / jQuery code yet to work with?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: are you just talking about the "rightli1" and "leftli1" items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that, or easier with class on your UL elements :

```
 $('li').click(function() {
      var id_other = $(this).attr('id').contains('right') ? 'rightli' : 'leftli';
      var id_number = $(this).attr('id').replace(id_other, '');

      $(this).hide();
      $('li#'+ id_other + id_number).show();
 });
```

No need class in fact :

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
     $(this).hide();
     $('ul').not($(this).parent()).find('li:eq('+ $(this).index() +')').show();
});
```

Another way, more simple :

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
     $('li:eq('+ $(this).index() +')').toggle();
});
```

If your LI elements are hidden at beginning.

Comment: Haven't thought about the `.replace()`. Nice idea.

Comment: impressiveness! ( i am trying that now) can you guide me how to do it easy with class?

Answer (score 1):

**In your code-**

```
<ul class="right">
   <li id="rightli1">item1</li>
   <li id="rightli2">item1</li>
   <li id="rightli3">item1</li>
</ul>
<ul class="left">
   <li id="leftli1">item1</li>
   <li id="leftli2">item1</li>
   <li id="leftli3">item1</li>
</ul>
```

**Here jquery-**

```
$('.right li').click(function () {
    var idx = $(this).index();
    $('.left li').eq(idx).slideToggle();
});
```

It will select parallel list to your body content. And keep in mind, avoid use of lots of id's one a single page, use class.

**Related demo-**

[Selecting parallel list](http://jsfiddle.net/Xq82u/)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$('ul').eq(0).children('li').click(function(){
   var index = $(this).index();
   $('ul').eq(1).find('li').eq(index).hide();
});

$('ul').eq(1).children('li').click(function(){
   var index = $(this).index();
   $('ul').eq(0).find('li').eq(index).hide();
});
```